# How to remove unwanted 2D packages from a Unity 2021.3 3D URP Project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, package, project, manifest

Because of bug in Unity Hub, when creating a new Project the only templates available are the following:
[image]

So the work around to start a 3D URP Project is to simply choose the 2D URP Template, let the project open in Unity, and then change the Renderer from 2D to 3D and change some graphics settings.
This works well, and Ive not encountered any issues with 3D URP functionality.
However, I now have a bunch of (unnecessary?) 2D packages in my root project folder:
[image]

How can I best delete them? I have read something about a `manifest?`, but I dont know how that works.

How do I get rid of these files and what other changes should I make in the project?(manifest?)

Comment: This was downvoted (not by me though) as it is not really a programming question and it shows you did not do research before asking. The window you are asking about is literally called Package Manager, does exactly what you need and is one of the core components of Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to create a 2D URP project and delete the 2D packages?
You can create a 3D project and then install the URP package from the package manager (open the package manager by clicking Window>package manager in the editor), in the package manager select Unity Registery and search "Universal RP", then just install the package and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Package Manger window to remove all unused packages.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).